# How to 'watermark' a PDF file?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, pdf, watermark

OK, I'm familiar with the whole concept and I've already managed to 'watermark' an `NSImage`.

This is how I'm doing it :

```
- (void)maskOne:(NSString*)filename atTarget:(NSString*)folder
{
    NSString* target = [self getTargetPathForFile:filename path:folder];

    NSImage* newImage;

    NSImage* oldImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filename];

    newImage = [self maskImage:oldImage withMask:[self imageWithSubviews]];

    [self saveImage:newImage asPNG:target]; 
}
```

where `[self imageWithSubviews]` returns an `NSImage` from an embedded black-bg box with some transparent text in it.

---

Now, in an bigger app of mine, as a sub-project, I'm trying to 'protect' exported PDFs by applying a watermark (nothing complicated, just a simple piece of text in the middle of **each** page, or something).

How would you go about it?

Comment: @H2CO3 Thanks for the recommendation! Any reference/resource available you could point me to?

Comment: here you are [a link to Apple's official guide.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH214-TPXREF101)

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon could you please post your solution here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CoreGraphics framework for modifying PDF content - read [Apple's official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH214-TPXREF101) on the topic.